# Get total number of members per branch_id by using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

````
 Members Table: Column: member_id, firstname, lastname, branch_id

 Branch Table: Column: branch_id, name etc ```
````

I want to display total number of members per branch.

Example:

```
BranchName Number of users
Durban     1000
Cape Town  2000
Mpumalanga 2500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a relation from branch to members you could do the below.

```
@foreach ($branches as $branch)
    <div>Name: {{ $branch->name }} </div>
    <div>Members: {{ {{ $branch->members->count() }}</div>
@endforeach
```